# Unwanted duplicate rows in pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm using pivot tables to structure my statistics.

I have recently been making changes to the data set and then created a new pivot table. However, this time there are duplicates in the row labels. For example, there is a duplicate of "1". Before it was 12345678 as row labels, however, currently it is 112345678.

Any idea of what my causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The changes you made to the data set? Pictures and a description of what you changed (or an example with dummy values if it's sensitive data) would help in identifying the problem (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pivot table to have information within it, it has to be referencing some data that resembles this... If you can provide a little more information you may get some help but the information provided is very limiting.

Also check out if the data source is all formatted as text or numerics.